# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method startListening on channel internet_speed)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm having the below error when trying to use the internet_speed package in flutter. This error occurs when I try to start the test. Anyone know any fix?

```
I/System.out(12436): port:80
I/flutter (12436): the errorMessage CONNECTION_ERROR, the 
speedTestError Socket is closed
I/flutter (12436): the errorMessage CONNECTION_ERROR, the speedTestError Socket is closed
W/1.raster(12436): type=1400 audit(0.0:100191): avc: denied { search } for name="battery" dev="sysfs" ino=6688 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c170,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs_batteryinfo:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
I/flutter (12436): the errorMessage CONNECTION_ERROR, the 
speedTestError Socket is closed
```

Minimal reproduction:
class SpeedTestPage extends StatefulWidget {
const SpeedTestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

```
@OverRide
State createState() => _SpeedTestPageState();
}
    
class _SpeedTestPageState extends State {
InternetSpeed internetSpeed = InternetSpeed();
 
    @OverRide
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    InkWell(
    child: Text("Click to start"),
    onTap: () {
    internetSpeed.startDownloadTesting(
    onDone: (double transferRate,
    SpeedUnit unit) {
    debugPrint(
    'the transfer rate $transferRate, the percent 100');
    },
    onProgress: (double percent,
    double transferRate,
    SpeedUnit unit) {
    debugPrint(
    'the transfer rate $transferRate, the percent $percent');
    },
    onError: (String errorMessage,
    String speedTestError) {
 debugPrint(
'the errorMessage $errorMessage, the speedTestError 
   $speedTestError');
  },
 );
   
 },
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

flutter clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The package [`internet_speed_test`](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_speed_test) only supports Android and iOS platforms. It's not possible to run it for the web platform.

[image]

Comment: Same error occurs on android. Even on various versions and types of packages from the author

Comment: What's the error on Android? Please edit the question and add it. Also, add a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)